# Direct integral

Tags: operator-theory

Let us assume that every w*-continuous bounded unital homomorphism from a separably acting type II_1 factor $M$ to some $\mathbb B(H),$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, is completely bounded. $(1)$

Let now $A$ be a separably acting type II_1 von Neumann algebra and let us consider it's integral decomposition $$A\cong \int_{\Gamma}^{\oplus}A_{\gamma}\,d\mu(\gamma)$$

where $A_{\gamma}$ is a factor. If $(1)$ is true and $u:A\to \mathbb B(K), $ where $K$ is a Hilbert space, is a w*-continuous bounded unital homomorphism, then how can we prove that $u$ is completely bounded ?